# How to get particular string from string array

Tags: c#

I have a string array for `Abc\r\n123PQR\r\n456` which i got from a container and I want only `"ABC"` and `"PQR`"using webdriver. How to get it ?

I have used `Split("\r\n")` but its only returning 2 strings `"ABC"`and `123PQR\r\n456`

Any suggestions? 
Language is C# using webdriver.

Comment: Can you show your actual code?  Split should have given you 3 strings based on the example you've given.  Also don't spam unrelated tags (I don't see how this pertains to java)

Comment: Added an edit to get rid of useless tags. This is just a question about c# strings and split.

Comment: That also does not look like a string array to me.

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`, `selenium` and `webdriver`?

Answer (score 1):

To get words in sequence try this

```
string sequence = "Abc\r\n123PQR\r\n456";

string[] itemsArray = sequence.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<string> itemsList = new List<string>(itemsArray);

List<string> itemsListFind = itemsList.FindAll(
    delegate(string item) 
    { 
        return 
            item.ToUpper().Contains("ABC") ||
            item.ToUpper().Contains("PQR"); 
    });

string[] result = itemsListFind.ToArray();
```

The result is:

```
{string[2]}
    [0]: "Abc"
    [1]: "123PQR"
```

Is it?

Comment: You can simplify your split by doing: Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) since the OP's string does not contain \r or \n independent of each other. This is assuming though they are truly looking for the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, according to test cases proposed:

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z].*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        // Split the string on line breaks, removing parts consisted of only numbers
        // ... The return value from Split is a string array.
        string[] lines = Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<=\n)(.[\d]*)(?=\r)|(?<=\n)(.[\d]*)(?=$)|(?<=^)(.[\d]*)(?=\r)", string.Empty), "\r\n");
        //Removing empty spaces with Linq
        lines = lines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) 
        {
            Match m = reg.Match(lines[i]);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                lines[i] = m.Value;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used the below code and it works fine,
   
string[] lines = Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(value, @"[\d]", string.Empty), "\r\n");

But the real problem started when I have some string value having numbers in name like
Actual name: 4547gaeey\r\n12345567mona2p\r\n123456lisa123\r\n8764438

I want to get output like :
Expected name: 2947gaeey,mona2p,lisa123

Comment: hm, I thought that you only wanted the names, like "gaeey", "mona" and "lisa" in this case.  I'm gonna update the code

Comment: actually why do you have "2947gaaey" as expected name? please give me the correct requirement so that I can build a regex for you

Comment: I have edited it @Monade . Take a look at it. Now the output for the last test case that you showed here is: "gaaey" , "mona2p" ,"lisa123"

Comment: Thanks. Actually i am creating an automated script, and I have to fetch some specific string from a container from UI. So for first time I have used ur earlier script of regex , and it had solved the issue. Then I got to know that the string could have digits too. For e.g. Sam2 , 265-paul etc. So in this case my previous script will fail.